# GMaps seems to request duplicate img and 404s

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

http://www.blue-adventure.com/home/

If you take a look over Gmaps + Slideshow section.
I converted the slideshow pictures from png to jpg and replaced urls on the respective posts, thus updating the slideshow.

Now there's some iframe being loaded in Gmaps section (hidden) loading the pngs again.
[image]

Try searching the img on source code to find it

```
http://www.blue-adventure.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/posts-inmersiones/punta-gavina/a-punta-gavina.png
```

It seems to affect Chrome, but not Firefox.
Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a preloading-mechanism of the embedded map.

When you click on the diver-icon in the map an infowindow appears which contains the images of the slideshow(the old png-versions), chrome obviously preloads the contents of the infowindows.

The 404 may be a result of the broken link below the images.

You'll need to update the embedded map to avoid the loading of the old images.